# RadioButtonGroups are not clickable if Item Text is changed

Tags: java, radio-button, vaadin, radio-group

I am fairly new to Vaadin and to Java, so also the obvious tips could be beneficial.

In my view, I have 5 RadioGroupButtons (Vaadin's Standard).
The major RGB changes the Item Text of the other four RGB.
A real life example would be to select a car brand (VW, BMW, Kia) and for every Brand there would be different models.

I tried having the ClickListener inside the MainView, RBG and RBG_Aggregat. Also tried to pass the different RBGs as variables to the different classes. Nothing worked.
There is not much documentation on these RadioButtonGroups.
Now I have found some examples of "binder" but I could not manage to get it working.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

The Code for the main View is the following: I added the comments where the problem is located.

```
@Route("test")
@PageTitle("test")

public class TestView extends VerticalLayout {
    HorizontalLayout hl =new HorizontalLayout();
    Gefährdungsbeurteilung gefährdungsbeurteilung=new Gefährdungsbeurteilung(1,"","","","","");
    RBG MG = new RBG("Mengengruppe");
    RBG WD = new RBG("Wirkungsdauer");
    RBG WF = new RBG("Wirkfläche");
    RBG FG = new RBG("Freisetzungsgruppe");
    RBG_Aggregat RBGAggregat= new RBG_Aggregat();//Main steering RBG

    public TestView(){
        hl.add(RBGAggregat.returnButton(),MG.returnButton(),WD.returnButton(),WF.returnButton(),FG.returnButton());
        add(hl);
    }

    public class RBG_Aggregat {
        public String selectedItem;
        public RadioButtonGroup radioGroup;

        public RBG_Aggregat() {
            this.radioGroup=new RadioButtonGroup();
            this.selectedItem="";
        }

        public RadioButtonGroup returnButton(){
            radioGroup.setItems("flüssig", "fest", "Gas/Aerosol");
            radioGroup.setLabel("Aggregat");
            radioGroup.addThemeVariants(RadioGroupVariant.LUMO_VERTICAL);
            addClickListener(event -> {
           if (radioGroup.getValue() == "flüssig") {
               gefährdungsbeurteilung.setAggregat("flüssig");
           }
           if (radioGroup.getValue() == "fest") {
               gefährdungsbeurteilung.setAggregat("fest");
           }
           if (radioGroup.getValue() == "Gas/Aerosol") {
               gefährdungsbeurteilung.setAggregat("Gas/Aerosol");
           }
  //if i comment the next for lines out, the RGB are clickable but the text is not changing.
                MG.updateHeader();
                WD.updateHeader();
                WF.updateHeader();
                FG.updateHeader();
 //if i do not comment out the privious 4 lines, the text is changing but the RBG are not clickable
            });
            return radioGroup;
        }
    }


    public class RBG{
        public ArrayList rbgitems;
        public String rbglabel;
        public RadioButtonGroup radioGroup;
        public String selectedItem;
        public String title;

        public RBG(String title) {
            this.radioGroup=new RadioButtonGroup();
            this.title= title;
            this.rbglabel=title;
            this.rbgitems= (ArrayList) gefährdungsbeurteilung.getDescription(title);
        }

        public void updateHeader(){
            radioGroup.setItems((ArrayList) gefährdungsbeurteilung.getDescription(getTitle()));
        }

        public RadioButtonGroup returnButton(){
            radioGroup.setItems(getRbgitems());
            radioGroup.setLabel(getRbglabel());
            radioGroup.addThemeVariants(RadioGroupVariant.LUMO_VERTICAL);
            return radioGroup;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public ArrayList getRbgitems() {
            return rbgitems;
        }

        public void setRbgitems(ArrayList rbgitems) {
            this.rbgitems = rbgitems;
            radioGroup.setItems(rbgitems);
        }

        public String getRbglabel() {
            return rbglabel;
        }

        public void setRbglabel(String rbglabel) {
            this.rbglabel = rbglabel;
        }

        public String getSelectedItem() {
            return selectedItem;
        }

        public void setSelectedItem(String selectedItem) {
            this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "RBG{" +
                    "rbgitems=" + rbgitems.toString() +
                    ", rbglabel='" + rbglabel + '\'' +
                    ", radioGroup=" + radioGroup +
                    ", selectedItem='" + selectedItem + '\'' +
                    ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

}
```

The Text for the different items originates form the following class.

```
public class Gefährdungsbeurteilung {

    private int id;
    private String WF;
    private String WD;
    private String FG;
    private String MG;
    private String Aggregat;
    private Boolean visible;
    

    public Gefährdungsbeurteilung(int id, String WF, String WD, String FG, String MG, String aggregat) {
        this.id = id;
        this.WF = WF;
        this.WD = WD;
        this.FG = FG;
        this.MG = MG;
        this.Aggregat = aggregat;
    }

    public List getDescription(String titel) {
        String aggregat= getAggregat();
        ArrayList description= new ArrayList();
        if (titel=="Freisetzungsgruppe") {
            description.add("niedrig");
            description.add("mittel");
            description.add("hoch");
            if (aggregat == "flüssig" || aggregat == "Gas/Aerosol") {
                description.clear();
                description.add("niedrig (Siedepunkt größer 150°C)");
                description.add("mittel (Siedepunkt zwischen 50 und 150 °C)");
                description.add("hoch (Siedepunkt kleiner als 50°C)");
            }
            if (aggregat == "fest") {
                description.clear();
                description.add("niedrig (Granulat, Pellets, Wachs)");
                description.add("mittel (körnig: Staub, der sich absetzt (z. B. Waschmittel, Zucker))");
                description.add("hoch (feinpulvrig: Staub, der in der Luft bleibt (z. B. Mehl, Toner))");
            }
        }
        if (titel=="Wirkungsdauer"){
            description.add("kurz (kürzer als 15 min pro Tag)");
            description.add("lang (länger als 15 min pro Tag)");
        }
        if (titel=="Wirkungsfläche"){
            description.add("klein (z.B. Spritzer)");
            description.add("groß (z. B. Kontakt mit Händen oder Unterarmen)");
        }
        if (titel=="Mengengruppe"){
            description.add("klein");
            description.add("mittel");
            description.add("groß");
            if (aggregat == "flüssig" || aggregat == "Gas/Aerosol") {
                description.clear();
                description.add("klein (Arbeitsmenge unter einem Liter");
                description.add("mittel (Arbeitsmenge unter 1000l)");
                description.add("groß (Arbeitsmenge über 1000l)");
            }
            if (aggregat == "fest") {
                description.clear();
                description.add("klein (Arbeitsmenge unter einem Kilogramm");
                description.add("mittel (Arbeitsmenge unter einer Tonne)");
                description.add("groß (Arbeitsmenge über einer Tonne)");
            }
        }
        return description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWF() {
        return WF;
    }

    public void setWF(String WF) {
        this.WF = WF;
    }

    public String getWD() {
        return WD;
    }

    public void setWD(String WD) {
        this.WD = WD;
    }

    public String getFG() {
        return FG;
    }

    public void setFG(String FG) {
        this.FG = FG;
    }

    public String getMG() {
        return MG;
    }

    public void setMG(String MG) {
        this.MG = MG;
    }

    public String getAggregat() {
        return Aggregat;
    }

    public void setAggregat(String aggregat) {
        Aggregat = aggregat;
    }


    public Boolean getVisible(String titel) {
        String aggregat= getAggregat();
        visible=Boolean.TRUE;
        if (titel=="Wirkungsdauer"|| titel=="Wirkungsfläche"){if (aggregat=="Gas/Aerosol"){visible=Boolean.FALSE;}}
        return visible;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean, that if you change the items of an radio-button-group, you can see the changed items, but if you click one in your browser, the item can not be selected? Have you tried adding a value change listener and debugged from there (e.g. does your server side code "unselect" at once)?

Comment: For me it looks like that you are trying to do this in overly complex manner and thus having a problem in your logic. All code is not here, thus hard to say it more precisely. Now I would recommend you to use value change listener in master RadioButtonGroup and in the value change event call slave RadioButtonGroup's setItems to set their items based on master selection. Also you should observe the value change of the slave groups with their respective value change event.

Comment: Also I would recommend to have a chat in Vaadin's Discord channel:  https://discord.com/channels/732335336448852018/783279629023969291

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue here is the clickListener.
It's added on the VerticalLayout: `addClickListener(event -> {`
So every time you are clicking on the entire layout your are changing the items of the radiobuttongroup.

You can do this:

`radioGroup.addValueChangeListener(event -> {`

It will work.

There are few things I noticed that is not working (or might not work):

- `titel=="Freisetzungsgruppe"` Always use equals for String in Java or Objects equals like `Objects.equals(titel, "Freisetzungsgruppe")`
- You can use List instead of generic List.
- You should also avoid non-ascii characters in your Java class Gefahrdungsbeurteilung instead of Gefährdungsbeurteilung.

In your case, the code looks really complicated because you are manipulating all the labels at the same place. You can split the code and only change the display label of the radiobuttongroup. For example with 1 radiobutton:

```
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout {
    HorizontalLayout hl =new HorizontalLayout();
    RadioButtonGroup<String> agregat = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
    RadioButtonGroup<String> mengengruppe = new RadioButtonGroup<>();

    public TestView(){
        agregat.setItems("flüssig", "fest", "Gas/Aerosol");
        agregat.setLabel("Aggregat");
        agregat.addThemeVariants(RadioGroupVariant.LUMO_VERTICAL);
        agregat.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
            if (e.getValue() != null) {
                updateMengenGruppeRenderer(e.getValue());

            }
        });
        hl.add(agregat);

        mengengruppe.setVisible(false);
        mengengruppe.setItems("klein", "mittel", "groß");
        mengengruppe.setLabel("Mengengruppe");
        mengengruppe.addThemeVariants(RadioGroupVariant.LUMO_VERTICAL);

        hl.add(mengengruppe);
        add(hl);
    }

    private void updateMengenGruppeRenderer(String value) {
        mengengruppe.setVisible(true);
        mengengruppe.setRenderer(new TextRenderer<>(item -> {
            String description;
            if (value.equals("flüssig") || value.equals("Gas/Aerosol")) {
                if (Objects.equals(item, "niedrig")) {
                    description = " (Siedepunkt größer 150°C)";
                } else if (Objects.equals(item, "mittel")) {
                    description = " (Siedepunkt zwischen 50 und 150 °C)";
                } else {
                    description = " (Siedepunkt kleiner als 50°C)";
                }
            } else {

                if (Objects.equals(item, "niedrig")) {
                    description = " (Granulat, Pellets, Wachs)";
                } else if (Objects.equals(item, "mittel")) {
                    description = " (körnig: Staub, der sich absetzt (z. B. Waschmittel, Zucker))";
                } else {
                    description = " (feinpulvrig: Staub, der in der Luft bleibt (z. B. Mehl, Toner))";
                }
            }
            return item + description;
        }));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question right, but if you're looking to change the values shown in one `RadioButtonGroup` based on the selection in another, the best way to accomplish that is by using a `ValueChangeListener`:

```java
public class HelloWorldView extends VerticalLayout {

  public HelloWorldView() {
    var data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    data.put("Fruits", List.of("Banana", "Apple", "Orange"));
    data.put("Vegetables", List.of("Carrot", "Onion", "Potato"));
    data.put("Drinks", List.of("Water", "Beer", "Wine"));

    var categoriesSelect = new RadioButtonGroup<String>();
    var itemSelect = new RadioButtonGroup<String>();

    categoriesSelect.setItems(data.keySet());
    categoriesSelect.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
      var selectedCategory = e.getValue();
      itemSelect.setItems(data.get(selectedCategory));
    });

    add(categoriesSelect, itemSelect);
  }
}
```

[image: Two radio button groups. The first one shows the categories: Vegetables, Drinks, Fruits with Fruits selected. The second group shows options Banana, Apple, Orange, with Apple selected.]